# Should I lock the table when creating user?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a user into User table.
These are my process.

1. continue when email and nickname are not exist
2. creates a user

I think if I didn't lock the User table while creating a user then email and nickname can be duplicated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid locks where possible. Instead, use a [unique index](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/), and simply insert the user. If the user or email exists, your query will return an error similar to:

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'john.doe@example.org' for key 'unique_email'

This should be done with **2 separate indexes**. One for email, and one for users. This has the following advantages, and almost zero disadvantages:

1. It enforces database consistency. At no point will 2 users have the same email address, nor the same username.
2. It avoids unnecessary locks.
3. It avoids [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt). Let's say down the line you add a user importer. In the importer you fail to check for duplicate accounts, or add in locks, or forget to check if the username or email exists. Your importer will work, and your database will now contain entries that duplicate each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to create a combined unique key on email and nickname

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_index_name ON user_table(email , nickname)
```

Edit: To address the comments below, we should as well create 2 more unique indexes for email and username, to make sure 2 users with separate emails can share the same username and vice versa.

Comment: I'd avoid doing this. You need to create **two separate indexes**, as in this case, users will be able to share the same email john.doe@example.org, or 2 users with separate emails can share the same username.

Comment: yes additional 2 indexes are necessary if we want to check for unique email and username as well